# How to make file-size and number of files quotas for anonymous upload on vsftp on RedHat (CentOS)?

Tags: centos, ftp, vsftpd

We have vsftpd service on our server but I didn't find a way to put limits on file size and total space available for anonymous file uploading (doing it via an account will make it harder - as our users are not super-users and even uploading a file via anonymous FTP sometimes is too hard).

We need to allow to upload files up to around 20Gb (and the total space should be around 150G).

Comment: This answer is almost identical to one asked previously. Simply apply quotas to the "nobody" user. (or whatever your system uses as a "guest" user) https://serverfault.com/questions/37737/quotas-in-vsftpd